# Notification text not showing if big text is too short

Tags: android

The following is the same code taken from the Android docs:

```kotlin
var notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
        .setContentTitle(emailObject.getSenderName())
        .setContentText(emailObject.getSubject())
        .setLargeIcon(emailObject.getSenderAvatar())
        .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                .bigText(emailObject.getSubjectAndSnippet()))
        .build()
```

What I have noticed is that if the text used to set the bigText is too short, the text used by `setContentText` will never get displayed. This seems to be a bug. I've tested this on Android 11.

Answer (score 0):

I love the Kotlin language! I think it's a new language that's fast and clean and easy to read.

Adding a new line character "\n" displays the text:

```
                .setStyle(Notification.BigTextStyle()
                .bigText("\n$txtRead"))
```